# azman - problem with registering Interop.AZROLESLib.dll to GAC

Tags: .net, gac, strongname, azman

I am struggling since 2 -3 hours to register the Interop.AZROLESLib.dll to gac using .net framework configuration tool. the error says "unable to add the selected assembly. the assembly must have strongname.....". Please help to create strong name and other stpes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For more detail : http://aspalliance.com/394_Installing_an_Assembly_in_GAC.all

1) Create an assembly key file

Use the sn.exe tool to create a key file:
sn -k StrongNameFile.snk

If your path environment variables aren't set, you'll have to go to the C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\FrameworkSDK\Bin\ directory to run sn.exe)
The filename "StrongNameFile.snk" can be any name you want.

2) Edit your assembly
Now you have to add a tag which will link your assembly key to the assembly:

using System.Reflection;
[assembly:AssemblyKeyFile("StrongNameFile.snk")]

Normally this is done in the utility AssemblyInfo.cs (vb) file.

3)Add your assembly to the GAC

gacutil /i AssemblyFileName.dll

To uninstall this assembly from the GAC, use the command:

gacutil /u AssemblyFileName

4) (Opional) Add your assembly to machine.config

Locate the  tag (for web apps,under ////)
Between the  tags, enter:

```
<add assembly="AssemblyFileName, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5edf592a9c40680c" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, i want to put COM (Interop.AZROLESLib.dll) in to the gac, this is a dll how can i change assembly info? assembly:AssemblyKeyFile("StrongNameFile.snk")]

Comment: create wrapper on that com componenet and make it as .net dll than you can do it easily

Comment: Ok i followed, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998336.aspx and it worked.